# How to connect to 2 linux servers to copy a file using talend

Tags: java, unix, components, remote-access, talend

I am using talend studio 7.3 and am attempting to connect to the old unix server and fetch a file from a location like:
cd /home/location/scripts/copying.csv
and want to use this file to be copied over into the target directory at a new unix server at the same location?

It would need to overwrite the existing script at the target location

I tried using tssh ,tsystem,tfilefetch but does not produce desired rsults and i am getting error as:
"executor has been shut down"

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Can you [edit] your question, and include your code that you have tried.  Also, please clarify "location like: cd /home/location/scripts/copying.csv"  -- I assume you meant a file `copying.csv' in a directory named `/home/location/scripts/` but you also listed a `cd` command?

Comment: Yes ,i was trying to describe the filepath as home/location/scripts and i would a cd to get there from my home folder after logging in

Answer (score 1):

SCP is what would normally be used in this scenario

```
$ scp username@oldmachine:/home/location/scripts/copying.csv /home/location/scripts/copying.csv
```

It would also overwrite a file with the same name if there was one.

Never used talend but according to [the documentation](https://help.talend.com/r/en-US/7.3/scp/tscpfileexists-tscpput-tscpclose-tjava-configuring-tscpget-component-standard-component) it is supported

Comment: Thanks i did a slight tweaked approach and incorporated tscp component,but since the target server has sudo permissions to get in,its displaying as "permission denied" when i try to copy it.How to overcome the permission issue?

Comment: try `ssh username@oldmachine "sudo cat /home/location/scripts/copying.csv" > /home/location/scripts/copying.csv`
you might be able to use this without 'sudo' as long as you have the Read permission.

It essentially writes the content of the remote copying.csv to the local copying.csv instead of transferring the file